# How to get the value of these created textboxes?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Whenever I am clicking on "ADD TEXTBOX" button it will create new +1("MULTIPLE")  HTML textbox with jQuery's append method but i am not get the logic to get their value in php.

```
$(w).append('<div><input type="text" name=/><a href="#" id="removes">Remove</a><br/></div>');
```

Suppose if I create 5 new textboxes than how to assign them name that it will not create problem when I will get the value with PHP & store it in database.

Comment: w is a div where i am going to add new element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$(w).append('<div><input type="text" name="textboxname[]"/><a href="#" id="removes">Remove</a><br/></div>');
                                              ^^^ add name like this
```

And you have get the value in PHP like this:

Suppose you are using `POST` method:

```
$fisrt = $_POST['textboxname'][0];
$second = $_POST['textboxname'][1];
```

Or you can use `foreach` loop like this:

```
foreach($_POST['textboxname'] as $values){
//you logic
}
```

Comment: yes i tried with foreach & it is working but can you help me in one more thing?can i give the text box name 3,4,5,6 which will increment as we add more

Comment: or can i give each new created textbox value of 3,4,5,6 and so on

Comment: @SangeetShukla where you want to add 3 give an example.

Comment: when even a new text box create it must have incremental name like 1,2,3,4,5,6 here i want to start it with 3,4,5,6,7 etc...hope get my question

Comment: @SangeetShukla yes, you can do it take a variable in js and put the value of it in the name.

Comment: var x=3; than name=x & x++ after increment .right??

Comment: @SangeetShukla do this: `var x = 3; $(w).append('<div><input type="text" name="'+x+'"/><a href="#" id="removes">Remove</a><br/></div>'); x++;` by the way you are  at right direction.

Answer (score 1):

How about like this?

```
for(var i=0; i<5; ++i){
  $(w).append('<div><input type="text" name=input" +
         i + "/><a href="#"     id="removes">Remove</a><br/></div>');
}
```

Then you can use similar looping on your PHP side.

```
for( i=0; i<5; ++i){//not sure the exact syntax of php
 echo $_POST['input'.i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the javascript when you are using this append method, use a variable and keep incrementing its value every time you append, use that variable value for the naming purpose.

It will be like name+1=name1 for first input
name+2=name2 for second input..

Answer (score 0):

Append input field as array

```
$(w).append('<div><input type="text" name="txt1[]"/><a href="#" id="removes">Remove</a><br/></div>');
```

txt1[] will make your text field as array then in php get txt1[] using foreach

```
if(isset($_POST['txt1'])){
   $txt_array = $_POST['txt1'];
   foreach(txt_array as $key => $value){
     echo $value . "<br>";
   }
}
```